# Reading Binary file till the end c++

Tags: c++

So i have this binary file with some player's data written in it. 
I want to print the hole file, ( i have class player that contains some data)
there is some data printed to the screen but after that an exception is thrown.

```
void Player::print_statistics()
{
    ifstream file; string str; Player plyr;
    file.open("player_database.dat", ios::binary);
    while(file.read((char*)&plyr, sizeof(Player)))
    {
        file.read((char*)&plyr, sizeof(Player));
        cout << plyr.full_name << "   " << plyr.ingame_name << "   " << plyr.age << "   " << plyr.hours_played << "\n";

    }
}
```

Exception thrown: read access violation. **_Pnext** was 0x148E2B4. occurred. 
  I tried the following:

```
while(!file.eof())
```

doesn't work

```
while(file>> string)
```

doesn't work.
This is the calss :

```
using namespace std;
class Player 
{
protected:
    string password;
    int age = 0;
    long int id_nmber=0 ;
    string email, ingame_name, full_name;
public:
// ...
};
```

Comment: What is `Player`? Are you trying to deserialise complex types? `_Pnext` suggests a standard library type like a container or `std::string`. You can't just byte-copy those; their direct contents are often just pointers to data on the original machine...

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings Simple class contains some attributes ( like name/ age .. ).

Comment: Show us exactly.

Comment: Are you sure you want the `;` at the end of the `while`? Also, you are doing an unchecked `read` within the body of the `while` as well.

Comment: @YassineMrabet  -- You may think the class is simple, but it may not be.  Please post the class.

Comment: As suspected, your code will not work for `Player`.  First, what is the last parameter to `read`?  It is `sizeof(Player)`, and that cannot work.  The `sizeof` is a compile-time value, thus it cannot change.  What if one of those strings contained 1000 characters?  How would `sizeof` figure out there are 1000+ characters to write to the file?

Comment: There we go; called it. :)

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, drop this immediately -> `file.read((char*)&plyr, sizeof(Player))`. You're writing raw binary data to a non-POD type. Results of such operation are undefined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55942970/4386278 too

Comment: @YassineMrabet [Check this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa071a40e6161fca).  That answer has to return "Yes" if that class can be used to read to and write to a file in binary fashion.  As you can see, the answer returned from querying whether `Player` is trivially copyable is "No".  If you want to verify this, here is the [same class with the `string` members removed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/deba30301518aa8e).  Now the answer is "Yes":

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "No" it isn't .. 
So i guess i should change everything to text file because i need this string type.

Comment: Use simple `char` arrays instead of `std::string`.  That would be one way.  Or keep the class as it is now and properly serialize the data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So i changed every string to a char*, will this function work ?

Comment: No it will not work if you just change to a pointer.  A pointer is not an array.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie what can i do then ?

Comment: `char name[SomeSize];` -- Wouldn't that be obvious?